# How to convert string to JSON object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am using jquery 1.3.2 and I can't use the parseJSON since it is added in 1.4.1 & I can't upgrade right now.

Is there any wat to get JSON object from string?

If this is a duplicate please send me the link.

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a couple of options, [see here](http://www.json.org/js.html)

- Javascript eval function
- JSON.parse() function

The eval function has some security issues associated with it, and the JSON.parse function has its own set of incompatibilities. I guess this is why JQuery has its own wrapper function. If you can't use JQuery 1.4+ though, these are two of your best options, without going looking for a specific JSON parsing library.

Comment: I am having a similar function jquery has. temporary.

Answer (score 1):

json2.js : http://www.json.org/js.html

Comment: This is the author comment on this file:On current browsers, this file does nothing,
prefering the built-in JSON object. Does this mean it won't work with latest browser?

Comment: No, it means that the Browser specific JSON object will take precedence over the javascript object. This means you get backward compatibility with browsers that do not have the JSON object.